# How to change the port for the npm run watch?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, npm, localhost

I am trying to watch the development using `npm run watch`. But it moved to http://localhost:3000 instead of http://localhost:8080. How to change this port 3000 to 8080? 
Because I am using the Tomcat server in 8080 port.

```
[BS] Proxying: http://localhost:8080
[BS] Access URLs:
 -----------------------------------------------------------------------
       Local: http://localhost:3000/server1/demo3/index.html
    External: http://192.168.126.1:3000/server1/demo3/index.html
 -----------------------------------------------------------------------
          UI: http://localhost:3001
 UI External: http://192.168.126.1:3001
 -----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

update bs-config.json file:

Eg:

```
 {
  "port": 8000,
  "files": ["./src/**/*.{html,htm,css,js}"],
  "server": { "baseDir": "./src" }
}
```

But in case of of angular2-cli, you need to provide at port argument like this:

```
ng serve --port 8000
```